# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: android, realm, unsatisfiedlinkerror, .so

I am creating Fingerprint appliation . In this application have `libNBioBSP.so` file inside this path `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi`. Adding Realm function for database concept. But when run the application getting error like.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libNBioBSP.so"
```

When run the application without Realm ,working well.

Answer (score 1):

Realm doesn't support `armeabi`, only `armeabi-v7a` and above. By the looks of it `libNBioBSP.so` doesn't come in a `v7a` variant?

This, unfortunately, confuses Android when it loads native code, which results in your application crashing like that. All native libraries must support the same set of architectures.

Unless you're able to build your native code for `armeabi-v7a`, you are unfortunately not able to combine Realm with your other native library.

Comment: thank you. I was changed folder from armeabi, to armeabi-v7a. After application working well